# Why's one of my useQuery hooks not returning undefined while the other one is?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, react-query

I'm using React Query and I'm not sure why one of my useQuery hooks is logging `undefined` while the other one is logging the correct data.  They're both async functions and are literally doing the same thing. I've been trying to debug this for a while but to no avail, I've hit a wall.

How can I fix it so that `console.log(winnersData);` also logs the correct data just like `console.log(data);`?

**Note:** Yes, `fetchUploads()` is returning data correctly when testing on Postman so we can rule out that nothing's being returned.

```
async function fetchUploads(){
    const headers = {
        "Accept": 'application/json',
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${authToken}`
    };

    const {data} = await axios.get('http://localhost/api/get-user-uploads-data', {headers});
    return data

}

async function fetchWinners(){
    const headers = {
        "Accept": 'application/json',
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${authToken}`
    };

    const {winnersData} = await axios.get('http://localhost/api/choose-winners', {headers});
    return winnersData
}

const { data } = useQuery('uploads', fetchUploads)
const { winnersData } = useQuery('winners', fetchWinners)
console.log(data); // returns correct data
console.log(winnersData); // returns undefined

return(...);
```

Comment: console.log the entire result of the `axios` request and add that to your question - `const fullData = await axios(...`, `console.log(fullData)`.

Comment: @BrianThompson I did that, I see results `{data: Array(3), status: 200, statusText: 'OK', headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}` so I'm not sure what the issue is :(

Comment: For some reason, you're destructuring twice. That amounts to `response.data.data` in one case, and to `response.winnersData.winnersData` in the other. We don't see what your `response` is, but it would explain why you get `undefined`.

Comment: @Bergi what do you mean by destructuring?

Comment: @luvs2spooge https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 1):

I think the confusion revolves around your first return being called data. Coincidentally, Axios requests return an object with a property called data, which you are successfully destructuring. They don't have a property called winnersData, hence `const {winnersData} = await axios.get('http://localhost/api/choose-winners', {headers});` is undefined.

Edit:

```
async function fetchUploads(){
    const headers = {
        "Accept": 'application/json',
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${authToken}`
    };

    const {data} = await axios.get('http://localhost/api/get-user-uploads-data', {headers});
    return data

}

async function fetchWinners(){
    const headers = {
        "Accept": 'application/json',
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${authToken}`
    };

    // const {winnersData} = await axios.get('http://localhost/api/choose-winners', {headers});
    // return winnersData
    // Remember, there is no winnersData on the object Axios is returning

    const {data} = await axios.get('http://localhost/api/choose-winners', {headers});
    return data
    // There is a data property for you to destructure (as there is on every successful Axios return), so we'll return that!

}

const data = useQuery('uploads', fetchUploads)
const winnersData = useQuery('winners', fetchWinners)
// I'm not sure what the shape of the data returned by these functions is, so I took out the destructuring. Remember, you can't destructure a property that isn't there.

console.log(data); // returns correct data
console.log(winnersData); // returns undefined

return(...);
```

Comment: ah ok, so what should I re-name `const {winnersData}` to then?  I've tried what you're referring to but it's still returning undefined.

Comment: oh wait... I get it.  Even If I use `const {data}` in my second return, it won't work because there already exists a `const { data } = useQuery('uploads', fetchUploads)` so `const { data }` isn't usable anymore since there'd be duplicate variables.  So what can I do in this case?

Comment: An Axios request returns an object with a property called data. When you are trying to get the data out of the request you can use object destructuring as you did with your first request, `const { data } = ...` The Axios object does not have a winnersData property, so destructuring it returns undefined.
What you need  to do is destructure data from both Axios requests. What you call them after that will, as you point out, need to be different.

I'll update my answer with what should be working code if that didn't make sense.

Comment: Yeah if you can update your answer with working code, that'd be great.  I kind of understanding what you're saying but I prefer having it laid out in front of me so I can truly grasp it :).  Thanks a lot in advance!